# Adding different classes to each list item

Tags: jquery

I've created a list and am trying to add a different class name to each one. Currently, I'm using this method:

HTML:

```
<ul class="sd-list">
   <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">List Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.sd-list:nth-child(1)').addClass('green');
$('.sd-list:nth-child(2)').addClass('red');
$('.sd-list:nth-child(3)').addClass('purple');
```

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a better method than the one I'm currently using. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that's awfully vague...is there any logic to what class is given to what list item?

Comment: It looks like you are adding style classes (as opposed to semantic ones). If the goal is to style these, why not just have selectors in your CSS file? e.g. `.sd-list > li:first-child`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the classes in an array:

```
var colors = ['green', 'red', 'purple'];

$('.sd-list').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    if (index < colors.length) {
        $(this).addClass(colors[index]);
    }
});
```

If the lists are all children of the same parent and you used `:nth-child(X)` to get the element at position `X` (instead of truly using it as *"the n-th child of parent"*), and you have a class for each position, you can also simplify it to:

```
$('.sd-list').addClass(function(index) {
    return colors[index];
});
```

---

But I agree with Vlad, you can easily write this directly in CSS:

```
.sd-list:nth-child(1) {
    /* rules */
}
/* etc */
```

Comment: Thank you. And yes... my first go was with CSS, but since I suck at jQuery, I thought I give it a shot. Thank you Felix for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {

      $(".sd-list li").each(function(index) {
            $(this).attr("class", "color" + index);
      });

});
```